# Escrow token is disabled on the current user

Tags: android

When I use the method "setResetPasswordToken" on Android 8.0 device.
It throw this error
`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Escrow token is disabled on the current user
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1945)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1891)
        at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setResetPasswordToken(IDevicePolicyManager.java:8856)
        at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setResetPasswordToken(DevicePolicyManager.java:2797)`

How do I need to resolve it?

Comment: I have set device owner

Comment: did you find a solution without QR code ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by enrolling DPC app used to reset passwords in Device Owner mode via QR code https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices#create_a_qr_code instead of setting DO via ADB.

Notice that clear method is deprecated https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#clearDeviceOwnerApp(java.lang.String)